# Why is `api_key` required for GitHub Releases Uploading with Travis?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I'm using Travis Enterprise and GitHub Enterprise and I have Travis configured to auto upload assets to my repo based on the instructions [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/).

My `.travis.yml` has a section like this and is current working fine:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  file: app.war
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
  api_key:
    secure: *********
```

My question is very simply why do I need the `api_key` section at all since my GHE repo already has a [Deploy Key](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) configured with Read/Write access. The Deploy Key gives Travis access to that repo and enables it to retrieve the code and perform the build in the first place. Shouldn't that Deploy Key be sufficient for Travis to also upload assets to Releases section of the repo?

Comment: Downvoted with no comment. That's interesting.

Comment: A deploy key is SSH Git access. The API key is to call the [release GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release) as a specific user.

Comment: @osowskit I see what you mean I think. So is the difference, then, more of an implementation detail rather than anything to do with security? I mean conceptually if I have a Deploy Key set up with r/w access I would expect that to be sufficient to enable uploading something to the Releases section of a repo.

Comment: Deploy keys are great to restrict access to single repositories for CI - especially if set to read-only.

API access has broader access to your account/Organization that is controlled by scope. IMO your OAuth token is a larger risk as it can be used as a password; however, it is revokable and can be limited to what resources it can access.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR** Deploy Keys interact with Git data; OAuth tokens allow API access to interact with GitHub.

A [deploy key](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) will grant Travis SSH Git access - read and write - and is scoped to a single repository. This enables SSH interaction with repositories.

The [release upload process](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases) requires that Travis have an [OAuth token](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases#Authenticating-with-an-Oauth-token) to interact with GitHub on your behalf. The [GitHub Releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release) requires this token as a specific user.